# Top level mutable variables in haskell

Tags: haskell, persistence

I have a a C++ program calling my Haskell program multiple times. But some data from the first calls needs to be retained for the subsequent calls. I know top-level mutable variables are not supported by default in Haskell but I guess I still need something like that.
(Writing my state to a file and reading it back in would work, but I want something more native)

On hackage I found libraries like global-variables or safe-globals but they all seem quite old and dependent on old versions of packages I already use.
Is there a canonical solution for this problem?

Ideally, I'd like to have the top-level functions:

```
getState :: IO Mystate
writeState :: Mystate -> IO ()
```

(I guess I should also mention that everything is done in one call of hs_init() in the FFI so the Haskell program doesn't really exit between calls)

Comment: Can your entry point not return a result and accept an argument? The thing calling it the first time can then pass that information around to whatever calls it the second time, which can pass it back in.

Comment: Here's [a detailed answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16811376/haskell-simulate-global-variablefunction/16811995#16811995) to a very similar question; it essentially expands on Mike Hartl's answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can create a global mutable variable:

```
myGlobalVar :: IORef Int
{-# NOINLINE myGlobalVar #-}
myGlobalVar = unsafePerformIO (newIORef 17)
```

The 
[haskell wiki](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Top_level_mutable_state)
gives this as current standard solution, while also discussing alternatives.