# How to define and use global array in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, global-variables, global

I am new in Haskell world. I have to create a game based on checkers board and would like to define global variable - an array representing board. Do you know how to define this array and use it (modify it) in functions?

Please, help me.

Comment: The question indicates that you're _very_ unfamiliar with how Haskell works. I'd suggest you to look into some introductionary works like [lyahfgg](http://learnyouahaskell.com/).

Comment: Yes, you're right. I've read this tutorial and I understand that "changing variable's value would be some kind of lie", but I really need to know how to create **mutable array** with global access.

Comment: The only cases where you actually need to create a mutable array with global access are when working with the FFI. Are you working with the FFI?

Comment: @mankers You really don't need a mutable global array.  You don't need anything global, nor anything mutable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although the concept of global variables is not encouraged at functional programming, you can have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16811376/haskell-simulate-global-variablefunction) solution and use *State Monad*  as mentioned here :

```
import Control.Monad.State
import qualified Data.Map as Map

funcs :: Map.Map String Double
funcs = Map.empty

f :: String -> Double -> State (Map.Map String Double) ()
f str d = do
  funcs <- get
  put (Map.insert str d funcs)

g :: State (Map.Map String Double) String
g = do
  funcs <- get
  if (Map.lookup "aaa" funcs) == Nothing then return "not defined" else return "ok"

main = putStrLn $ flip evalState funcs $ do {f "aaa" 1; g}
```

Comment: It should be noted that `State` works rather badly with actual arrays: updates will be done purely-functional, i.e. every change to a single member of the array costs _O_ (_n_). `Data.Map`, as you propose, is better in this regard, it has _O_ (log _n_) updates. For really performance-critical stuff, one of the dedicated [mutable array types](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-0.10.11.0/docs/Data-Vector-Mutable.html) should be used, those have _O_ (1) updates (but they only work in the `ST` or `IO` monad).

Comment: Another option that performs very well is to use `IntMap`.  This can be generalized to keys of a type isomorphic to integers, such as `Enum` instances (e.g. the `enummapset-th` package) or `Hashable` instances (`unordered-containers`).

Answer (score 1):

Check out: http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Arrays#Mutable_IO_arrays_.28module_Data.Array.IO.29

Remember, evey mutation in haskell is inside a Monad i.e you describe the mutations using a moand and then you run the monad by passing it the initial value (state) that will go through the mutations.