# Make variable from input accessible from the whole code

Tags: haskell

Is this even possible? I have a main that saves an Int (width) given by the user as a variable, but I need that variable in a bunch of other functions... Is there a way to do this other than adding 'width' as an argument to every function?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Haskell - simulate global variable(function)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16811376/haskell-simulate-global-variablefunction)

Comment: @Rakete1111 OP doesn't need to write state, only read.

Comment: @Alec But you can't change variables in any case in Haskell, right? Nonetheless, OP needs to write the input from the user into it.

Comment: @Rakete1111 Yes, Haskell is immutable. Yes, despite that we still can simulate mutable state. But just initializing a reading store that you pass around doesn't need the full power of state. I'll add an answer.

Comment: The question is vague about whether the other functions need to change the value of the "global" variable. A `State` monad *might* be appropriate.

Comment: @chepner Agreed. Also, on second thought this seems like a question that has probably been asked before. Maybe it would be better to find another post with a thorough answer for which this is a duplicate...

Comment: No - "Is there a way to do this other than adding 'width' as an argument to every function?" - everything you can possible do to fix this is just that in disguise (state monad, reader monad, etc). Depending on your code, it may be easy or hard to integrate this additional abstraction.

Answer (score 3):

I'll show a simple example of reader monad usage.

This code:

```
area :: Double -> Double -> Double
area height width = height * width

main = do
  width <- fmap read getLine
  let result = area 42 width
  print result
```

Becomes:

```
import Control.Monad.Reader

area :: MonadReader Double m => Double -> m Double
area height = do
  width <- ask
  return (width * height)

main :: IO ()
main = do
  width <- fmap read getLine
  let result = runReader (area 42) width
  print result
```

This seems more complicated, but it's actually quite nice when you have a lot of "configuration" parameters to pass around.

```
import Control.Monad.Reader

data Config = Config { width :: Double, color :: String, etc :: String }

area :: MonadReader Config m => Double -> m Double
area height = do
  w <- asks width
  return (w * height)

main :: IO ()
main = do
  w <- fmap read getLine
  c <- undefined -- todo get color param
  e <- undefined -- todo get etc param
  let result = runReader (area 42) (Config w c e)
  print result
```